# Unable to see JTextField

Tags: java, swing

My GUI Window for button `addFinishingInformation` does not show up. I have the same method written for other buttons and they work perfectly fine.

I have been debugging it for a while but have not been able to make the fields or anything show up. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
JButton addFinishingInformation = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add Finishing Information") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame addFinishingFrame = new JFrame("Add Finishing Information");
        addFinishingFrame.setSize(700, 500);
        addFinishingFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel addFinishingPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel finishingDateFieldLabel = new JLabel("Date:");
        finishingDateFieldLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 160, 25);
        addFinishingPanel.add(finishingDateFieldLabel);

        final JTextField finishingDateField = new JTextField(50);
        finishingDateField.setBounds(140, 40, 160, 25);
        addFinishingPanel.add(finishingDateField);

        Date todaysDateIs_2 = new Date();
        Calendar cal_2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal_2.setTime(todaysDateIs_2);
        String formatedTodaysDate_2 = cal_2.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/"
                + (cal_2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
                + cal_2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        finishingDateField.setText(formatedTodaysDate_2);

        JLabel finishingChalanNoLabel = new JLabel("Chalan no. :");
        finishingChalanNoLabel.setBounds(10, 70, 160, 25);
        addFinishingPanel.add(finishingChalanNoLabel);

        final JTextField finishingChalanNumber = new JTextField(50);
        finishingChalanNumber.setBounds(140, 70, 160, 25);
        addFinishingPanel.add(finishingChalanNumber);

        addFinishingFrame.add(addFinishingPanel);
        addFinishingFrame.setLayout(null);

        JButton addFinishingInformationToDatabase = new JButton(
                new AbstractAction("Add finishing information to database") {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Customers customer = new Customers();

                        Date todaysDate_3 = new Date();
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.setTime(todaysDate_3);
                        String formatedDate_3 = cal.get(Calendar.DATE)
                                + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                                + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        customer.addFinishingInformation(sentToFinishing.getText(),
                                formatedDate_3,
                                finishingChalanNumber.getText(),
                                quantityInWeightFinishing.getText(),
                                lengthInMeterFinishing.getText(),
                                totalShawls.getText());
                    }

                });
        addFinishingInformationToDatabase.setBounds(110, 300, 300, 70);
        addFinishingPanel.add(addFinishingInformationToDatabase);
        addFinishingFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

});

addFinishingInformation.setBounds(460, 360, 250, 70);
mainPanel.add(addFinishingInformation);
```

Comment: Which is your mainPanel Layout?

Comment: Its the panel in which includes all others. Hope that helps. Basically I am adding all panels to a main panel. It is the first screen that is shown when the GUI runs.

Comment: You have a Container (JFrame) over this JFrame you have to add Panels (mainPanel) this panel should have a Layout (GridLayout, BorderLayout, etc.) I can't know why the button doesn't shows up. In the JFrame instance, are you call a pack() method?

Comment: You will want to create and post a smaller and simpler example program, your [mcve] to allow us to more fully understand your problem. General recommendations include refactoring your code as you appear to have too much code in this class. Create smaller and simpler classes as this will allow for easier debugging and enhancing. Don't show multiple JFrames. Avoid null layouts and setBounds.

Comment: When using `null` layouts you should expect the unexpected and undesirable. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    addFinishingFrame.add(addFinishingPanel);
    addFinishingFrame.setLayout(null);
```

Quit using null layouts!!! Don't use setBounds(...)!!!

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

You don't see anything because the size of your panel is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

That is why you use a layout manager. The layout manager will calculate the size for you so you don't need to worry about it.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.